# FSEvents - get PID of the process that performed the operation

Tags: macos, filesystems, fsevents

On OS X, using the [FSEvents](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005289-CH1-SW1) API, I can easily get file and directory notifications (created, removed, etc), for paths of interest. However, I was wondering if there is any way to get the PID or name of the process that performed the operation (e.g. created the file). I know that you can get this information if you are monitoring the file system in real-time (see: [fs_logger](https://web.archive.org/web/20180924040312/http://osxbook.com/software/fslogger/download/fslogger.c)), but I'd prefer to use `FSEvents` since it allows you to specific exactly what paths to monitor and works in a callback manner (so likely less CPU intensive?).

Answer (score 2):

Apple has a relatively new (macOS 10.15+) `C` framework called [Endpoint Security](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/endpointsecurity) which comes close to meeting all of the filesystem event monitoring requirements you're looking for:

- Efficient / Event-driven model ([es_new_client()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/endpointsecurity/3259700-es_new_client))
- Granular event type subscription model ([es_subscribe()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/endpointsecurity/3228854-es_subscribe))
- rich event context including `pid`, `uid`, and much more (e.g. An event message for file creation ([es_event_create_t](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/endpointsecurity/es_event_create_t)) includes an [es_process_t](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/endpointsecurity/es_process_t) field with process details)
- No support (yet?) for subscribing to filesystem events based on 'path(s) of interest' but events can be 'muted' (masked) based on source process (e.g. [es_mute_process()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/endpointsecurity/3228851-es_mute_process)). That might offer an improvement over parsing *all* events for the paths you're interested in. You can always file a feature request with Apple for that.

Apple has been pushing developers to adopt this new framework for a while now in favor of previous monitoring APIs (like 'legacy' kernel extensions that leverage `KAUTH` or `MAC`; the `OpenBSM` API) so it's the only solution I can recommend investing in going forward (beyond `FSEvents`).

There are some WWDC sessions and example projects available on the subject: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/endpointsecurity/monitoring_system_events_with_endpoint_security